# Why is the proto-italic reconstruction of "corpora" "*korpezā"?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, latin, reconstruction, plurality

I was studying rhotacism and I came across the word *corpora* (plural of *corpus*). I would reconstruct the proto-italic form as **korpoza*, but I saw the entry on Wiktionary and it says that the actual reconstruction is **korpezā*.

Is this reconstruction accurate? If it is, what causes this vowel alternation, considering the singular form **korpOs* and it's later result *corpOra*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *e* in the oblique stem seems to go back to Proto-Indo-European: compare the Germanic cognate, nom sg **hrefaz*, nom pl **hrif**i**zō*.

Even if the PIt form had been ***korpozā*, *-e-* would be the expected development within Latin, due to medial vowel reduction. The *-o-* results from the *o* vowel in the nom sg spreading to other forms by analogy. Since this was analogy rather than a regular sound change, we see regularized words like Old Latin *corpos, corp**o**ris* next to unregularized ones like *latos, lat**e**ris*. Finally, regular sound change turned *o* in final syllables into *u*, giving the nom sg *corp**u**s*.

Comment: That's what I thought when I compared to *hrifizō too. Thanks :)

Comment: Do we know if this "e to o" analogy happened before of after the rhotacism process? Was it *korpeza > *korpera > corpora or *korpeza > *korpoza > corpora?

Comment: @ErgativeMan I don't know off the top of my head, but both processes were happening within the timeframe of attested written Latin, so there's likely evidence somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This word corpus ~ corpor- belongs to the same type as genus ~ gener-.
PIE neuters with an alternation *g^enos ~ *g^enes-.
As regards your question about relative dating, I would say that schwatization of unstressed medial vowels in Latin (> e/i) is older than rhotacism. So I would say that the path *korpeza > *korpera > (late leveling) corpora seems more likely than the path *korpeza > *korpoza > corpora, as the second path conflicts with schwatization of unstressed medial vowels in Latin. Vowel e in *korpeza is the regular reflex of an unstressed medial vowel in Latin.

Comment: How does the second path (by which I’m guessing you mean the ‘other’ path, that is, _*korpezā_ > _*korpera_ > _corpora_) conflict with schwatisation? Analogical restitution of _-o-_ can happen at any stage, regardless of the expected form of the vowel at the time.